# SQL: looking for rounded duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, rounding

I have a table that possibly seems to have transactions that are rounded to the nearest dollar before being reversed off

Given something like this:

```
AccountID  Transaction
1           20.05
1           -20.00
1           17.00
2           32.35
3           40.78
3           -41.00
4           15.00
4           -15.00
5           10.03
5           10.00
```

I want to see how many accounts have this pattern of a value, and a rounded negative counter-part. So, I want to pull AccountIDs 1 and 3 from the table above, for example.

I am not interested in AccountID 4, as that is an exact (absolute value) match, or AccountID 5, which has a "rounded duplicate" but is not a negative counter-part.

Any one know how I might accomplish this in SQL?

Comment: Tag the DBMS you are using, also rounding 20.05 usually goes up to 20.1, maybe you mean truncating instead of rounding?

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio. The values are rounded to the nearest dollar, not the nearest tenth of a dollar. They weren't rounded/truncated in SQL itself-- the data was like this when we got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare with rounded values.

```
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    Transactions AS T
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'inverted rounded operation detected'
        FROM
            Transactions AS N
        WHERE
            T.AccountID = N.AccountID AND
            ROUND(T.[Transaction], 0) = -1 * ROUND(N.[Transaction], 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have multiple transactions that match.  Hence, you should use `row_number()` for the matching:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by accountid, floor(transaction) order by transaction) as seqnum
      from transactions t
     )
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.accountid = t.accountid and
                    floor(t2.transaction) = floor(t.transaction) and
                    t2.seqnum = t.seqnum
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Round all the positive transaction values and find all the accounts that have an equal negative value.

```
select acct.accountid
from
    acct
    inner join (
    select
        accountid,
        round(transaction, 0) as whole_trans
    from
        acct
    where
        transaction > 0
        and transaction != round(transaction, 0)
    ) as unround on unround.accountid = acct.accountid
where
    unround.whole_trans = -1 * acct.transaction;
```